# Assetic in Symfony3 with CSSREWRITE

Tags: css, symfony, assetic, slick.js

I am using bower to manage many common assets and have run into an issue. I am trying to use [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to have a rotating carousel and I'm running it all through Assetic to combine and minify assets.

Here are my stylesheets in Twig:

```
{% stylesheets
    "vendor/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css"
    "vendor/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css"
    "vendor/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
    "vendor/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"
    "vendor/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css"
    "vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"
    "vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css"
    "css/*.css"
    "scss/*.scss"
    "@SHUDirectoryBundle/Resources/public/css/*.scss"
    filter="cssrewrite,scssphp,?uglifycss"
    output="css/combined/myshu.min.css"
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Here is my Assetic config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    node: /usr/bin/nodejs
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifyjs2:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
        uglifycss:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifycss
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
```

In the slick-theme.css file it references the following:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('./fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('./fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('./fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
```

I was under the assumption that CSSREWRITE would take the relative path ./ and write it to the direct path vendor/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/slick.woff for example.

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved itself. I'm not sure if assetic dump wasn't working correctly but it suddenly starting working while I was doing some other CSS changes.